# Error 26 - Visual Studio 2013 SQL

Tags: sql-server

My friend has a problem regarding local server when trying to create a new SQL Server database from Data Connections. We searched online and found out that somehow it has to do with something called the SQL Browser which can be located in the Microsoft Services window. He has not got the SQL Browser in the list. What programs does he need to install?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order for anyone to help, you should include your code, somethings you have tried, and what error messages you are receiving.

Comment: Search for you problem before posting a question

Comment: Perhaps it's better to have your friend to directly ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to SQL Server Data Tools, it sounds like this is what they need but I cant be sure without seeing the error message

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh297027

Comment: he basically cannot locate his pc on the network. not being listed in dropdown menu

http://imgur.com/UsjfMOX

Comment: that is something completely different than what you first suggested, this is  more than likely a network issue due, possibly down to firewall rules

Comment: ok thanks for your reply martpendle will check if its the firewall